# Redux Form: Validate NumberInput with argument from component props

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using Redux-Form v.7.3.0 and I want to validate a NumberInput Field with a number that is stored in the state and also in props of my component that holds that Field.

This is my Field:

```
<Field
   name={MyCompononent.stackabilityName}
   component={NumberInput}
   validate={checkIfInsertedValueIsSmallerThan(this.props.stackability)}
   normalize={notNegativeAndToInteger}
/>
```

And I want to have something like in the documentation here [Field Validation Documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/)

This is the interesting part:

```
const minValue = min => value => value && value < min ? `Must be at least ${min}` : undefined
```

Where this is used like this inside the "validate" prop of my Field: minValue(5).
I dont want to achieve this. I want to pull something from the state/props of my component where the Field component is located in order to dynamically insert the minimum value.

I hope there is some elegant way to do this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/), when you pass a function to your `validate` prop of the `<Field>` component, this function receives the following parameters:

```
customValidator(value, allValues, props, name)
// value: The current value of the field
// allValues: The values of the entire form
// props: Any props passed to the form
// name: Field name provided
```

So in your case you can just do this:

```
<Field
   name={MyCompononent.stackabilityName}
   component={NumberInput}
   validate={checkIfInsertedValueIsSmallerThan}
   normalize={notNegativeAndToInteger}
/>

const checkIfInsertedValueIsSmallerThan = (value, allValues, props, name) => {
   const stackability = props.stackability;
   // do something...
   return error;
}
```

Comment: Good hint, thanks! But how do I pass my stackability-value to the props of the validator now? Are there all the props my "MyComponent" Component contains?

Comment: Yes, it contains all the props passed to the form / component within which the `<Field>` exists.